# How to set a focus to TextBox in Avalonia

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have TextBox and Button, when I click Button, the text from TextBox sends to server. And TextBox loses focus. How i can set focus to the TextBox after Button click? I've read about `FocusManager`, but I don't understand how to use it((

Answer (score 2):

I done it with Behaviors.
Behavior class

```
    public class FocusOnPropertyChangedBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PropertyChanged += FocuseControl;
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.PropertyChanged -= FocuseControl;
    }
    private void FocuseControl(object sender, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!AssociatedObject.IsFocused) AssociatedObject.Focus();
    }
}
```

Xaml code

```
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <custom:FocusOnPropertyChangedBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get focus only on start, use AttachedToVisualTree instead of PropertyChanged